# Corda H2 Connection error "Connection is broken: "unexpected status 256" [90067-192]"

Tags: h2, corda

I try to connect to H2 database exposed by Corda node, using IntelliJ IDEA IDE - connection tests passes, however when I try to actually access the database I get

```
Connection is broken: "unexpected status 256" [90067-192]
```

Database is up and running (as the node exposing it works fine). I use URL given by the application at startup (ie jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:64667/node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure that the version of the client library you are running matches the version that the node is running - otherwise weird errors like the above manifest. Check the version of `com.h2database:h2` located in `build.gradle` in the node directory